# How do I search for a pattern in a serial number?

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo, preg-match

I have a database which contains the following :

```
pnid     partnumber       desc       code
====     ==========       ====       ====
1        123-12345        hdd        CMYK
```

So, the `code` field contains the pattern of the serial number I am looking for. What I would like to do is that I would like to fetch all the codes from my database, then check if a user input matches the code and display the part number of the matching code.

So saying that my input is `ECMYK123456` then the function would return `123-12345`.

I am really at lost. All I have is my basic PDO connection.

```
<?php
function checkPattern($inputString) {
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "123456";
    $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=3parsfdb',$dbuser,$dbpass);  

    $dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $query = $dbconn->query("SELECT * FROM `partnumber` WHERE '%$inputString%' LIKE `ctcode`  LIMIT 1");
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        return $row['partnumber'];
    }
}

echo checkPattern("ECMYK12345");
?>
```

When I try the function, it returns nothing. What is wrong with the code?

Final Code :

```
<?php
function checkPattern($inputString) {
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "123456";
    $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=3parsfdb',$dbuser,$dbpass);  

    $dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $query = $dbconn->query("SELECT * FROM `partnumber` WHERE '$inputString' like concat('%', ctcode, '%') LIMIT 1");
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        return $row['partnumber'];
    }
}

echo checkPattern("ECMYK12345");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groan:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM partnumber
 WHERE "ECMYK123456" like concat('%', code, '%')
```

Note that it can't use an index on code.

Comment: Hi Alain, thanks for the answer. But I am looking for a function. Also, I have thought of that idea and implemented it. I have edited my question. My problem now is it doesn't return any value.